# What does initialize_main (&argc, &argv) do?

Tags: c, linux, gnu-coreutils

I 'm reading coreutils source code to learn programming under linux.

I find that in most of the programs like ls.c, cat.c, they invoke the macro function initialize_main() at the first few lines. So I looked into system.h to find the implementation:

```
/* Redirection and wildcarding when done by the utility itself.
Generally a noop, but used in particular for native VMS. */
#ifndef initialize_main
# define initialize_main(ac, av)
#endif
```

I don't understand why define such a macro and I don't understand the comment.

Comment: if you observe where and how these macros are using in that files you would come to know.

Comment: The comment explains it reasonably well "Generally a noop, but used in particular for native VMS.". So under linux, it's a nop, nothing. VMS probably does something different for argument handling. linux is not VMS.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the GNU coreutils as a start because they contain all kinds of workarounds for obscure and obsolote operating systems. I've personally learned a lot from reading the source code for BSD utilities, which are much cleaner in terms of code (although they sometimes use BSD-specific APIs, but you'll find those).

Comment: Is VMS even around any more?  Seems about as relevant as CP/M these days.

Comment: It is, unfortunately.

Comment: @larsmans I will have a try. I just finished reading apue.

Comment: This code was changed and the reference to VMS replaced with OS/2: [commit 1](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/92519ce05878ddb78056ea2693ff986e2ac05730#diff-15426c0feb74edbf64f3665c398b00b5), [commit 2](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/70d8d0f874d11990be48b7b6b70c2c274000b3da#diff-15426c0feb74edbf64f3665c398b00b5)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The first step in understanding the comment is to know what VMS is. So here's a link for that:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS

The next step is to understand redirection and wildcarding. In Linux and other members of the unix family, a command like

```
cat foo* > /tmp/foolist
```

will call the `main` function of `cat` with `argv` containing the matches for `foo*`. The output file `/tmp/foolist` will already be open as `stdout` before `main` is entered.

VMS doesn't do that. `cat` will find the unexpanded string `"foo*"` and the redirection operator `>` in its argv. So the utility itself (`cat`) must do the redirection (opening the output file) and wildcarding (replacing `"foo*"` with `"foo1", "foo2", "foo3"`). That's what `initialize_main` will do on VMS. On unix, it'll do nothing ("Generally a noop").

Answer (score 11):

This is left over from times gone by. OpenVMS is an operating system which roughly competed with Unix in the past. There is still a fair amount of OpenVMS running in the world, but HP have dropped support for it and it will be going away in the next 10-15 years.

Anyway, this function is used on OpenVMS to allow stdout and stderr redirection on VMS.

Since `cat foo.txt > stuff.txt` on Unix, the `cat` command only sees one argument `foo.txt`, but on VMS, which knows nothing of the `>` symbol, the `cat` command sees 3 arguments.

The code inside `initialize_main` on VMS, allows the basic unix style commands to support output redirection, such as `ls` and

OpenVMS later added a command called `pipe` which allows redirection to work via any command.

You can view the source code for initialize_main on VMS here: [Link](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFUQFjAE&url=http://listserv.educause.edu/cgi-bin/wa.exe?A3=ind0603&L=security&P=286156&E=1&B=------%253D_NextPart_000_019E_01C64DBF.048846D0&N=ssn2libidfilter.c&T=application%252Foctet-stream&ei=rHtVUsHzFZH94AP9t4GgAw&usg=AFQjCNFFLfwCfrYzogIim6-Kyi3ib_FsaQ&sig2=FlMjFj4eRom2_9XRKGggxQ)